# Summation of the "product" of two sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have two individual sequences,
how can I find the summation of their product?

Formally:

> Let $\lbrace f_n\rbrace,\lbrace g_n\rbrace$ be the two sequences. Find: $$\sum_{i = 1}^n f_ig_i$$

Comment: If you are looking for the value of $\sum f_ng_n$ from $\sum f_n$ and $\sum g_n$ you can't get it.  Let $f_1=x, g_3=y,$ all other elements $0$.  Then $\sum f_ng_n=0$, but $\sum f_n=x, \sum g_n=y$ can be anything.

Comment: You seem to be asking us to find the value of some quantity, which by definition is a sum of products of unknown quantities: *c'est impossible!*

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be a ring and let $R^\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of all sequences $(f_1,f_2,\dots)$ with $f_i\in R$. Define a multiplication '$\star$' on $R^\mathbb{Z}$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
(f_1,f_2,\dots) \star (g_1,g_2,\dots) = (f_1\cdot g_1,f_2\cdot g_2,\dots)
\end{equation}

where $'\cdot'$ is the multiplication in $R$. Then for any two sequences 
$(f_1,\dots)$ and $(g_1,\dots)$, we can define the *summation of the first $n$ terms of the product* of $(f_1,\dots)$ and $(g_1,\dots)$ as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \cdot g_i
\end{equation}

Comment: Shouldn't that be $f_i . g_i$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @QthePlatypus Spot on. Thanks.

Comment: @user259242 how about Abel's Lemma?

Comment: Can't it be an alternative?

Comment: @ShivamTripathi What about it? Are you referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem ?

Comment: Nope...search Abel's lemma.

Comment: @ShivamTripathi I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean, 'can the summation of the product be defined in some other way?' then of course the answer is 'yes'!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts. Visit this link bro

Comment: @ShivamTripathi I'm not sure what this or any other lemma has to do with your question. You appeared to be asking what the 'summation of the product' of two sequences might be. I gave what I consider to be an answer.

Comment: @user259242 Hmm...thank you :)